# Error getting location on IBM MobileFirst Platform

Tags: jquery, geolocation, location, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm developing a mobile application on ibm mobile first platform. I am using version 7.0. I'm trying to get the Location information of the Android device, but although I tried several methods, I didn't get the location information. 
My permissions in android manifest file are correct and complete. My code and the logcat errors I got below. Thanks.

My codes:

```
var showPosition = function(position) {
    WL.Logger.debug("got a position");
    var latitude = Number(position.coords.latitude).toFixed(2);
    var longitude = Number(position.coords.longitude).toFixed(2);
    alert('<b>Longitude:</b> ' + position.coords.longitude + '<b>Latitude:</b> ' + position.coords.latitude);
    //$("#currentLocation").text(latitude + " / " + longitude);

};

var positionError = function(err) { 
    WL.Logger.debug("failed to get  a position");
    $("#status").text("position error" + err); 

};

WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition(showPosition, positionError, {
        timeout : 30000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        maximumAge:15000
    });
```

Logcat Erros:

```
V/GpsLocationProvider(  918): reportStatus status: 3
V/GpsLocationProvider(  918): reportStatus status: 1
I/System.out( 3766): IntentService[CrashUploaderService] calls detatch()
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766): Error uploading log:
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766): dbxyzptlk.db240408.I.h: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
dbxyzptlk.db240408.H.y.a(panda.py:424)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
dbxyzptlk.db240408.H.y.a(panda.py:346)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
dbxyzptlk.db240408.L.K.a(panda.py:472)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
com.dropbox.android.exception.d.a(panda.py:129)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
com.dropbox.android.exception.d.a(panda.py:52)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at     
com.dropbox.android.exception.CrashUploaderService.onHandleIntent 
(panda.py:33)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage 
(IntentService.java:65)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766): Caused by: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLNullSession.getPeerCertificates 
(SSLNullSession.java:104)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify (AbstractVerifier.java:93)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
dbxyzptlk.db240408.L.Q.createSocket(panda.py:173)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection 
(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:214)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open 
(AbstractPoolEntry.java:167)  
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open 
(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:125)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal 
(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1312)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute 
(DefaultRequestDirector.java:702)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute 
(AbstractHttpClient.java:694)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute 
(AbstractHttpClient.java:516)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute 
(AbstractHttpClient.java:494)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       at 
dbxyzptlk.db240408.H.y.a(panda.py:394)
I/com.dropbox.android.exception.d( 3766):       ... 9 more
```

Comment: What if you go to Settings -> Apps -> <your application name> -> Permissions and enable location permission ( if it is not there already)?
Also, what if you try the application out side a building - assuming this is an issue getting geo coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is location permission for this application my device. I also have GPS signals in my current environment.

Comment: Mr. Vivin, as you said, was able to get the location information when I was out of the building. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try changing location modes such as High accuracy ,battery saving and device only ,you might get location inside building

Answer (score 0):

High accuracy setting uses and looks for GPS signals along with network, wifi for location triangulation. It is sometimes known , not to work indoors when a GPS lock cannot be obtained.

Try the application outdoors, or fallback to a lower accuracy mode that primarily relies on cellular network for location. That should give you better results indoors.

Comment: My problem of getting the location unfortunately did not fully recover. In many different Android versions, I can't get the GPS signal in my experiments. There is another interesting situation: I installed an application called GPS Test on my mobile device. This application tests whether you can receive GPS signals from your environment. When I try to get a coordinate from my own application immediately after receiving the signal from the GPS Test application, I can receive coordinates in a few seconds without any problem. Is there anyone who can help?